# Primary and foreign keys dilemma in Snowflake Data Model

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling

I am building a DQ testing application in Snowflake. Below is a simplified version of the data model (I renamed objects for the sake of clarity). I have multiple config tables for different tests (e.g. `unique_tests` each has `test_id` column (serving as PK) which is an MD5 hash of key columns to help avoiding duplicate tests).

There is also a result table `test_results`, with the results for every test type run keeping history of the jobs.

Now I am adding a table `test_impact_category` where the results with issues can be categorized by users in terms of impact (e.g. high impact, low impact etc).

I don't see a use case to create a separate primary key in `test_impact_category` table as this is snowflake where primary keys are not enforced and not used for indexes.

So the controversy here is:

- It actually makes sense to have foreign key referencing another foreign key (many) (`test_results.test_id` (many) = `test_impact_category.test_id` (one))
- There are reasons not to add impact columns to test config tables

So if in terms of data modelling best practices and common sense, I am curious how other experienced modellers/engineers would model this in Snowflake?

[image]

Comment: To understand how to model different test types you need to investigate inheritance and super/subtypes. To model m:m relationships you will need an intersection table

Comment: In my case it’s many to one, where FK is one. The purpose to document relationship in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no dilemma as foreign key can only reference PK/UK.
So I guess this relationship cannot be documented in the DDL.
Keeping the post, may be there will be some interesting answers and some other people can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of modelling, my approach it would be the below:

- Table Tests that contains all tests together. test_id -> PK
- Table test_impact_category , has field (test_id, impact_category_id) -> PK
  || test_id -> FK (Tests - test_id)
  Note that this table it would be used to load the information into test_results table
- Table impact_category, has field (impact_category_id) -> PK
- Table test_results, has field (test_id) -> FK (Tests - test_id)
  || impact_category_id -> FK (impact_category - impact_category_id)